# .ogg audio file not being played in chrome 112

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

have an app where attached .ogg audio file , it was working fine earlier , file being loaded, play button also working but sound not being heard.

same file works fine in firefox and edge.

is there something changed in chrome or I have to enable any flag to listen ogg file?

here is sample code

```html
<audio src="file.ogg" preload="metadata" id="audioPlayer" 
controlslist="nodownload" type="audio/ogg; codecs=opus" controls autoplay />
```

there is no error in console, when click on audio it show playing.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There should be no closing slash for that opening tag and it requires a closing tag: `</audio>`

Comment: no, its not working with </audio> also

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: how does it invalid? in network it say 206 ( means partial success ) status for ogg file

Comment: I already showed you and the standard is readily available for you to read.

Comment: did you see what I have replied? I have changed it to </audio> like you suggest but still its not working and FYKI there are no invalid thing is HTML otherwise how does other browser render it. this is all about incorrect semantcis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently issue was with system, check Volume Mixer and found out that audio was muted for the chrome.